# Getting error when running pig: Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant -Dhadoopversion=23 jar', and try again

Tags: hadoop, ant, apache-pig

So I installed pig last night, decompressed the tar, and also edited my .bashrc to include:

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.12.0 
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
```

Last night I ran pig -h, ran some load commands, etc. it was working perfectly. Now this morning I try to run any pig command and it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant -Dhadoopversion=23 jar', and try again
```

So I try to run `ant -Dhadoopversion=23 jar` and I get this:

```
-bash: ant: command not found
```

My question is: why was it running find last night but this morning it won't work? What am I doing wrong? And also - do I have to somehow reinstall ant? I went to /usr/local/bin/ and there is no ant directory. I also run ant -version and I get command not found.

But why was it working last night? What's different now?

Comment: Have you deleted ant installation folder by any chance?/

Comment: Did you installed AND compiled it yesterday with ant, or just run it ? Try to cd to the location `/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.12.0` and run it again.

Comment: @glefait yesterday I just installed and it ran well... I did not have to manually execute the compilation. I have tried reinstalling the pig but no luck.

Comment: And yes, I tried it from /usr/lib/pig-0.12.0

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ls` in `/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.12.0`?

Answer (score 0):

this error come from the pig binary:

```
 if [ -f $PIG_HOME/pig.jar ]; then
    PIG_JAR=$PIG_HOME/pig.jar
else
    PIG_JAR=`echo $PIG_HOME/pig-?.!(*withouthadoop).jar`
fi

if [ -n "$PIG_JAR" ]; then
    CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:$PIG_JAR"
else
    echo "Cannot locate pig.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again"
    exit 1
fi
```

Your variable  `$PIG_HOME` is therefore undefined and for some reason could not been set automatically. Just do:

```
export PIG_HOME=/path_to_your_pig
```